# Multi-Runtime Targeting of Library for Nuget

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, nuget, .net-standard

I have a library that's currently built with .NET 4.0 and deployed to Nuget. The library doesn't have a lot of dependencies and seems to work fine in .NET Standard and Core projects as well.

The library when added manually to a Standard or Core project was throwing compatibility errors. This was remedied by modifying the .csproj file to remove non-needed references. It now looks like this.

```
<ItemGroup>
   <Reference Include="System" />
   <Reference Include="System.Core" />
   <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
</ItemGroup>
```

This seems solution seems to make the library function correctly with both Core and Standard. The compatibility warnings are now gone when adding the library manually to a Standard or Core project, even though the library is still built with .NET 4.0. However, after publishing to Nuget, and then downloading the library via Nuget I still receive this warning.

"Warning **** Package '******' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project."

After much annoyance and investigating, I realized the library still seems to work in a both Standard and Core projects, but I am not sure if it's using .NET 4.6.1 to actually run the library based on this warning.

So my question is, how do I properly deploy the package to Nuget to properly target Multiple runtimes? Do I need multiple projects built in each runtime? If so can I package it as one package still, or do I need a different version for each runtime? Not sure what the best practice is here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to change the csproj to use the new SDK format, and use `<TargetFrameworks>`. For example, [here's Dapper's project file](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/blob/master/Dapper/Dapper.csproj) which builds for 3 TFMs - the key is:

```
<TargetFrameworks>net451;netstandard1.3;netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>
```

combined with a few decisions via `Condition` attributes that influence which package or assembly references to add for each TFM - you can see the results of these conditions in the "Dependencies" view on nuget [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper/). When you `dotnet pack -c Release`, or build in the IDE with the "Generate NuGet package on build" option enabled (Package tab, project properties), it will generate the `.nupkg` for you in the build output, which will internally contain the 3 TFMs.

Comment: @Tronald yeah, the tooling for multi-targeting has evolved *hugely* recently - I guess it is just now a much more common thing to need to do, so it was worth making it painless

Comment: Just a heads up for anyone else looking. I had to port this project into .NET Standard from a .NET Framework project prior to using this solution. It only took a few minutes, but worked really good!

Comment: a well Explained answer